# Find if the sequence $\left((-1)^n + \frac1n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find out if the following sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ will either converge or diverge.
$$
a_n = (-1)^n + \frac1n
$$

If the limit converges, I need to find its limit.

I tried plugging in various numbers for n besides 1, but I am not entirely sure if it really does converge.

Comment: Consider the two subsequences $(a_{2n})_n$ and $(a_{2n+1})_n$. If the sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges, then these two must also converge to the *same* limit.

Comment: On the other hand, $|a_n| \le |(-1)^n|+|1/n| \le 2$ for all $n$. Also, it does not diverge.

Answer (score 3):

$a_n=(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}$

Observe that $\displaystyle a_{2n}=1+\frac{1}{2n} \Rightarrow \lim_{ n \to \infty}a_{2n}=1$

But $\displaystyle a_{2n+1}=-1+\frac{1}{2n+1} \Rightarrow \lim_{ n\to \infty}a_{2n+1}=-1$

So limit is not unique. Thus it is not convergent.